# Create a CSV file from marklogic using Java Client Api(DMSDK)

Tags: csv, marklogic, java, marklogic-corb

I want to create a csv file for 1.3M records from my marklogic db . I tried using CORB for that but it had taken more time than i expected.
My data is like this

```
{
"One": {
"Name": "One",
"Country": "US"
}, 
"Two": {
"State": "kentucky"
}, 
"Three": {
"Element1": "value1", 
"Element2": "value2", 
"Element3": "value3", 
"Element4": "value4",
so on ...
}
}
```

Below are the my Corb modules

Selector.xqy

```
var total = cts.uris("", null, cts.collectionQuery("data"));
fn.insertBefore(total,0,fn.count(total))
```

Transform.xqy(Where i am keeping all the elements in an array )

```
var name = fn.tokenize(URI, ";");
const node = cts.doc(name);
var a= node.xpath("/One/*");
var b= node.xpath("/Two/*");
var c= node.xpath("/Three/*");
fn.stringJoin([a, b, c,name], " , ")
```

my properties file

```
THREAD-COUNT=16
BATCH-SIZE=1000
URIS-MODULE=selector.sjs|ADHOC
PROCESS-MODULE=transform.sjs|ADHOC
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask
EXPORT-FILE-NAME=Report.csv
PRE-BATCH-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.PreBatchUpdateFileTask
EXPORT-FILE-TOP-CONTENT=Col1,col2,....col16 -- i have 16 columns
```

It had taken more than 1 hour for creating a csv file . And also for trying in cluster i need to configure a load balancer first. Whereas Java Client api will distribute the work among all nodes without any load balancer.

How can i implement the same in Java Client APi , i know i can trigger transform module using `ServerTransform` and `ApplyTransformListener` .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient
            ("localhost", pwd, "x", "x",  DatabaseClientFactory.Authentication.DIGEST);

  ServerTransform txform = new ServerTransform("tsm"); -- Here i am implementing same logic of above `tranform module` .

  QueryManager qm = client.newQueryManager();
  StructuredQueryBuilder query = qm.newStructuredQueryBuilder();
  query.collection();

  DataMovementManager dmm = client.newDataMovementManager();
  QueryBatcher batcher = dmm.newQueryBatcher(query.collections("data"));
  batcher.withBatchSize(2000)
         .withThreadCount(16)
         .withConsistentSnapshot()
         .onUrisReady(
           new ApplyTransformListener().withTransform(txform))
         .onBatchSuccess(batch-> {
                   System.out.println(
                       batch.getTimestamp().getTime() +
                       " documents written: " +
                       batch.getJobWritesSoFar());
         })
         .onBatchFailure((batch,throwable) -> {
           throwable.printStackTrace();
         });

  // start the job and feed input to the batcher
  dmm.startJob(batcher);

  batcher.awaitCompletion();
  dmm.stopJob(batcher);
  client.release();
}
```

But how can i send the csv file header like that one in CORB(i.e. EXPORT-FILE-TOP-CONTENT) . Is there any documentation for implementing `CSV` file ? Which class will implement that ?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Note that ApplyTransformListener isn't usually used for exporting content, but for transforming it in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest option is ml-gradle [Exporting data to CSV](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Exporting-data#exporting-data-to-csv) which uses Java Client API and DMSDK under the hood.

Note that you'll probably want to install a server-side REST transform to extract only the data you want in the CSV output, rather than download the entire doc contents then extract on the Java side.

For a working example of the code required to use DMSDK and create an aggregate CSV (one CSV for all records), see [ExporToWriterListenerTest.testMassExportToWriter](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/marklogic/client/test/datamovement/ExportToWriterListenerTest.java#L63-L119).  For the sake of SO, here's the key code snippet (with a couple a minor simplification changes, including writing column headers (untested code)):

```
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputFile)) {
  writer.write("uri,collection,contents");
  writer.flush();
  ExportToWriterListener exportListener = new ExportToWriterListener(writer)
    .withRecordSuffix("\n")
    .withMetadataCategory(DocumentManager.Metadata.COLLECTIONS)
    .onGenerateOutput(
      record -> {
        String uri = record.getUri();
        String collection = record.getMetadata(new DocumentMetadataHandle()).getCollections().iterator().next();
        String contents = record.getContentAs(String.class);
        return uri + "," + collection + "," + contents;
      }
    );

  QueryBatcher queryJob =
    moveMgr.newQueryBatcher(query)
      .withThreadCount(5)
      .withBatchSize(10)
      .onUrisReady(exportListener)
      .onQueryFailure( throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace() );
  moveMgr.startJob( queryJob );
  queryJob.awaitCompletion();
  moveMgr.stopJob( queryJob );
}
```

However, unless you know your content has no double quotes, newlines, or non-ascii characters, a CSV library is recommended to make sure your output is properly escaped.  To use a CSV library, you can of course use any tutorial out there for your library.  You don't need to worry about thread safety because ExportToWriterListener runs your listeners in a synchronized block to prevent overlapping writes to the writer.  Here's [an example of using one CSV library, Jackson CsvMapper](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/marklogic/client/test/datamovement/ExportToWriterListenerTest.java#L63-L119).

Please note that you don't have to use ExportToWriterListener . . . you can use it as a starting point to write your own listener.  In particular, since your major concern is performance, you may want to have your listeners write to one file per thread, then post-process to combine things together.  It's up to you.

Comment: As you said `Note that you'll probably want to install a server-side REST transform to extract only the data you want in the CSV output, rather than download the entire doc contents then extract on the Java side` . You mean instead of loading document`(i.e. const node = cts.doc(name))` and extracting contents`(i.e.var a= node.xpath("/One/*"))` . You want to try like this `var value = cts.doc(name)/One/*` .